# Text overlaps background when I shrink browser size even when height set to 100%?

Tags: html, css

I've spent the past 2 hours trying to figure out how to solve this problem but with no luck. I am having an issue with the text overlapping the background as well as the footer when I minimize the browser size. The html, body and divs are set to a height of 100% but there persists a vertical overlap. I would like the text to stay in the container and the container size to adjust the browser size when minimized, as well as keep the footer at the bottom.

Thank you so much, greatly appreciate it!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Webtwo ipsum blekko insala</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Webtwo ipsum blekko insala joost zinch babblely, akismet kosmix 
quora zoosk, plaxo chegg eduvant. Yuntaa blippy lanyrd zynga jajah, cloudera 
squidoo gooru. Stypi eskobo rovio hojoki vuvox jaiku unigo, bebo disqus 
airbnb udemy. Mog cotweet palantir imvu wikia zillow cuil, wikia sclipo 
squidoo heekya. Chartly prezi qeyno spock chartly glogster, joost ideeli 
skype edmodo, wufoo rovio mog palantir. Joukuu yoono oovoo yammer vuvox 
convore, zillow sifteo diigo oooooc zooomr convore, napster edmodo woopra 
omgpop. Zoosk lijit zynga squidoo oovoo divvyshot elgg, handango zillow 
eskobo kazaa. Yuntaa whrrl bitly divvyshot kosmix unigo, edmodo bitly 
omgpop. Jabber etsy zooomr yoono cuil, napster xobni jumo. Meevee elgg 
blippy qeyno, imeem etsy.

            <br>

        Tumblr xobni lijit, loopt. zillow wikia. Rovio dropio stypi disqus, 
heroku. Zynga cloudera spock zoodles kippt ning, kiko loopt vuvox grockit. 
Hipmunk ifttt joyent sclipo, ifttt odeo. Waze zanga empressr, eskobo. plaxo. 
Zappos movity oooj jajah imeem, voxy doostang ning.  Ning jajah odeo zimbra, 
yuntaa koofers. vuvox oooooc. eduvant zapier elgg. Wikia skype nuvvo joost 
bitly 
sococo jiglu, airbnb akismet ebay cotweet. Zanga meevee spock klout weebly 
sclipo hojoki qeyno wesabe, bebo akismet appjet twones bubbli doostang.</p>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  h1{

     font-size: 30px;
     color: #F82370;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 70px auto 50px auto;

  }

 .content{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 5% auto 5%;
}

.container{
  background: #17263c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 4px solid #6B1946;
  color: #405699;
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: justify;
  }


.footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background: #4ADBC8;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the height:100% in container class, you will fix this issue.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height: 100%;` instead of `height: 100%;`

```
.container {
   min-height: 100%;
   //other css...
}
```

```css
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  h1 {

     font-size: 30px;
     color: #F82370;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 70px auto 50px auto;

  }

 .content{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 5% auto 5%;
}

.container {
  background: #17263c;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border-top: 4px solid #6B1946;
  color: #405699;
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
  }


.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background: #4ADBC8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Webtwo ipsum blekko insala</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Webtwo ipsum blekko insala joost zinch babblely, akismet kosmix 
quora zoosk, plaxo chegg eduvant. Yuntaa blippy lanyrd zynga jajah, cloudera 
squidoo gooru. Stypi eskobo rovio hojoki vuvox jaiku unigo, bebo disqus 
airbnb udemy. Mog cotweet palantir imvu wikia zillow cuil, wikia sclipo 
squidoo heekya. Chartly prezi qeyno spock chartly glogster, joost ideeli 
skype edmodo, wufoo rovio mog palantir. Joukuu yoono oovoo yammer vuvox 
convore, zillow sifteo diigo oooooc zooomr convore, napster edmodo woopra 
omgpop. Zoosk lijit zynga squidoo oovoo divvyshot elgg, handango zillow 
eskobo kazaa. Yuntaa whrrl bitly divvyshot kosmix unigo, edmodo bitly 
omgpop. Jabber etsy zooomr yoono cuil, napster xobni jumo. Meevee elgg 
blippy qeyno, imeem etsy.

            <br>

        Tumblr xobni lijit, loopt. zillow wikia. Rovio dropio stypi disqus, 
heroku. Zynga cloudera spock zoodles kippt ning, kiko loopt vuvox grockit. 
Hipmunk ifttt joyent sclipo, ifttt odeo. Waze zanga empressr, eskobo. plaxo. 
Zappos movity oooj jajah imeem, voxy doostang ning.  Ning jajah odeo zimbra, 
yuntaa koofers. vuvox oooooc. eduvant zapier elgg. Wikia skype nuvvo joost 
bitly 
sococo jiglu, airbnb akismet ebay cotweet. Zanga meevee spock klout weebly 
sclipo hojoki qeyno wesabe, bebo akismet appjet twones bubbli doostang.</p>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code issue is container height 100%; desktop is good but mobile device overlap footer section replace this code your container section.  with media query

```
.container{
  background: #17263c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /*============== This one ==================*/
  border-top: 4px solid #6B1946;
  color: #405699;
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: justify;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:990px){
    .container{
      height: auto;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix height 100% is creating that issue. So please use below CSS,

```
    .container {
        background: #17263c;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 95%;
        border-top: 4px solid #6B1946;
        color: #405699;
        font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
        line-height: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 1.5px;
        text-align: justify;
        padding: 1px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

I have reduced footer height(5%) from 100% document height to view container + footer without scroll in covered screen. Also added padding(Adjust inside paragraph margin) and box sizing(Covered border and padding in height).